# MinIO change user credentials (secret key)

Tags: administration, minio

I'm running a distributed MinIO Cluster with 4 nodes with multiple user accounts for different purposes/buckets. I need to write a convenience script or simple web app for users where they can change their passwords.

How can I change a password for an existing user?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this closed Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/1066) there is no other way than calling the `mc` tool directly. Managing user accounts with the help of the MinIO SDK is not available at the moment but may be implemented in the future.

At the moment the only possibility to change the SECRET_KEY of a user is to create a new user via `mc admin user add`. Next Monday I will test whether calling the command again means that groups / policies are no longer assigned to the corresponding user.

Answer (score 1):

The access credentials for the root user which are added on the docker yaml file cannot be changed from the web gui.

However, you can use a minio client with your root credentials to setup a new user and set the new user's policy to consoleAdmin. When the new admin logins on the web gui, they now can change their password.